# What does the value that pdf.w returns mean and how does the method work in PyFPDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyfpdf

I've been using the PyFPDF library for a while now, and when I was looking at other programmers codes I encountered a method that looks like this: (mostly It was used to set the width of columns in a table)

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.w
```

I checked what doest the `pdf.w` method returns and it gives me a float number equal to **210.0015555555555**. I'm wondering what does this method do and what does the float number mean centimieters, millimeters, pixels or something else?

I've printed the value of `pdf.w` and can't figure out what does it mean.

Comment: That's an attribute. Methods are functions, called with `()`.

Comment: This is an undocumented, internal attribute. You should avoid using it if possible

Comment: Seems like w = width. Agree with @Barmar

Comment: One of the arguments to `FPDF()` is `units`, so maybe `w` is in those units. What happens if you specify a different unit when constructing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of @Barmar's comments says, if you try to execute the following code, you obtain the **width of the page** (and not of the cell of a table) in the different unit of measure (*mm*, *cm*, *inch*, *point*):

```
from fpdf import FPDF

# default unit of measure is mm
pdf = FPDF()
print(f"Width Page = {pdf.w} mm (default unit of measure)")

pdf = FPDF(unit='mm')
print(f"Width Page = {pdf.w} mm")

pdf = FPDF(unit="cm")
print(f"Width Page = {pdf.w} cm")

pdf = FPDF(unit="pt")
print(f"Width Page = {pdf.w} point")

pdf = FPDF(unit="in")
print(f"Width Page = {pdf.w} inch")
```

The output of the execution of the previous code is:

```
Width Page = 210.0015555555555 mm (default unit of measure)
Width Page = 210.0015555555555 mm
Width Page = 21.000155555555555 cm
Width Page = 595.28 pt
Width Page = 8.267777777777777 inch
```

For details see the documentation of the [class FPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/FPDF/index.html).

### The width of a column

To build a table by PyFPDF you have to add a cell or multi_cell one after the other and set the attibute `w` of the cell or multi_cell when you construct these objects:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

# unit of measure is mm => for the cell width too
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.set_font('Times')
pdf.add_page()

# set width of the cell = 10 mm
pdf.cell(w=10, h=5, txt='value', border=1)

# set width of the multicell_cell = 100 mm
pdf.multi_cell(w=100, h=5, txt='multicell value', border=1)
```